# Exception handling for different inputs in Python

Tags: python

i am a beginner in python and i've tried to create a BMICalculator program and i am currently facing an issue
first up when you open the program it asks the user for their height and weight input
and i have created a try-exception handling for when a user tries to put a string into their Height/Weight input
But the problem is, when a user enters their Height properly, and then uses a string for their Weight, my ValueError exception does show up, but makes the user enter their Height again which is not user friendly,
So what i want to do but don't know how is:
To ask the user again for their Weight input not Height, as they have already entered that
My Code:

```
import math
import time


def BMICalculator():
    print("BMI Calculator!")
    try:
        Height = float(input("Enter your Height: "))
        Weight = float(input("Enter your Weight: "))
        Result = Weight / (Height / 100) ** 2

        print("Your BMI is: ", round(Result, 1))

        if Result <= 18.5:
            print("You are underweight")
        elif Result <= 24.9:
            print("You are healthy")
        elif Result <= 29.9:
            print("You are overweight")
        elif Result > 29.9:
            print("You are obese")
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid number")
        BMICalculator_NoWelcomingMessage()


def BMICalculator_NoWelcomingMessage():
    try:
        Height = float(input("Enter your Height: "))
        Weight = float(input("Enter your Weight: "))
        Result = Weight / (Height / 100) ** 2

        print("Your BMI is: ", round(Result, 1))

        if Result <= 18.5:
            print("You are underweight")
        elif Result <= 24.9:
            print("You are healthy")
        elif Result <= 29.9:
            print("You are overweight")
        elif Result > 29.9:
            print("You are obese")
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter a valid number")
        BMICalculator_NoWelcomingMessage()


def enter_again():
    user = input("Do you want to enter again?: ").lower()

    while user not in ['yes', 'y', 'no', 'n']:
        print("Please enter a valid input")
        user = input("Do you want to enter again?: ").lower()
    if user not in ['yes', 'y']:
        print("Have a nice day!")
        time.sleep(1)
    elif user not in ['no','n']:
        BMICalculator_NoWelcomingMessage()
        enter_again()


BMICalculator()
enter_again()
```

Comment: Instead of ```BMICalculator_NoWelcomingMessage()```, why don't you call ```BMICalculator()```? Also, keep in mind the maximum recursion limit

Answer (score 0):

Well, the reason that happens is because you have a single catch statement for both the inputs, and if either of them throws an error, you restart the entire process.

You can fix this with a minor modification, have the two inputs in separate catch blocks, and have a while true loop to keep asking for a valid input till you get one.
Here's what I said in code:

```py
def BMICalculator():
    print("BMI Calculator!")
    while True:
        try:
            Height = float(input("Enter your Height: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number")
    while True:
        try:
            Weight = float(input("Enter your Weight: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number")
        
    Result = Weight / (Height / 100) ** 2
    print("Your BMI is: ", round(Result, 1))
```

Note: You can probably parse the input in a separate function, and call that function when taking input for weight and height, would make the code cleaner. Something like this perhaps:

```py
def parse_input(InputName):
    while True:
        try:
            value = float(input(f"Enter your {InputName}: "))
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("Please enter a valid number")
    return value

def BMICalculator():
    print("BMI Calculator!")
    Height = parse_input("Height")
    Weight = parse_input("Weight")
    Result = Weight / (Height / 100) ** 2
    print("Your BMI is: ", round(Result, 1))
```